# Why does IntelliJ mark distributionUrl as unused in maven-wrapper.properties?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm fairly new to Spring.

I used https://start.spring.io/ to bootstrap a new Spring project and load it in IntellJ IDEA. When making the initial commit, IDEA remarked that there was an unused variable in `.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties`:

> distributionUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/4.5.4/apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.zip

From the README of [maven-wrapper](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper#using-a-different-version-of-maven) I can tell it's used to control which maven version is used by the wrapper. Then why does IntelliJ wrongfully mark it as unused and how do I fix it?

Comment: There are limits to what IntelliJ can detect from looking at your code.  You can usually Alt-Enter (or similar) to tell it that this particular check should be disabled at this location when it gets it wrong.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know IntelliJ could whitelist specific occurrences!

Comment: Also you should not commit anything in `.mvn` unless you have very good reason to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered recently such a "problem" which is not really a problem. Let me explain: IntelliJ underlined some 'unused' properties in my Spring Boot project. Those properties were not directly used in my Java code but in dependencies. So IntelliJ was wrong when underlining them but I think there is not much we can do. It's just a king of warning, not a blocking error.

I think you face the same problem as me and we have to accept there is no real solution !

Comment: Since you have the same problem, I just sent a support request about this to JetBrains. Will update this post if I get some relevant info from them.

Comment: They indeed don't have a better option available right now and suggest voting for this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146205 As an alternative, they give the same tip Thorbjorn also shared: you can suppress that specific inspection.